# Moving the camera in the direction it's facing, with ThreeJS

Tags: javascript, vector, three.js

Say I have a camera placed at:

```
{
  x: 10,
  y: 30,
  z: 20
}
```

It's rotation is:

```
{
  x: 0.1,
  y: 0.2,
  z: 0.3
}
```

I want to move the camera 1 unit from it's current position in the direction it's facing.

How do I do calculate the cameras new position?

I'm using ThreeJS.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `THREE.Camera` class extends the `THREE.Object3D` class.
You can get the camera direction with [the `getWorldDirection` method from the base class](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D.getWorldDirection):

> It returns a vector representing the direction in which the camera is looking, in world space.

When you have this `direction` vector you can use it to move the camera in the desired direction:

```
var direction = new THREE.Vector3();
camera.getWorldDirection( direction );
```

To move only 1 in that direction you can simply do:

```
camera.position.add( direction );
```

If you want to move more you could for example use [the `multiplyScalar` method from the `THREE.Vector3` class](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Vector3.multiplyScalar) and multiply with the desired distance.

```
distance = 10;
camera.position.add( direction.multiplyScalar(distance) );
```

Comment: THREE now complains ".getWorldDirection() target is now required" so you can pass it a Vector3 and then `direction = camera.getWorldDirection(vector);' returns the result into 'direction' and also put's it in the new vector.  The reasoning for the change, written by WestLangely who posted the efficient answer below, is here: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/12231

Comment: @kellycode Thanks for your comment. I updated the answer so it is working with the latest three.js version. I also updated the broken links.

Answer (score 5):

The camera looks down its local negative-z axis. So to move the camera in the direction it is facing, use this method:

```
camera.translateZ( - distance );
```

This is the most-efficient method.

three.js r.78

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is using React Three fiber :->

```
    let a = perspCamRef.current.rotation.x
    let b = perspCamRef.current.rotation.y
    let c = perspCamRef.current.rotation.z
    var direction1 = new THREE.Vector3(a, b, c);
    let direction = perspCamRef.current.getWorldDirection(direction1)
    let distance = 1;
     perspCamRef.current.position.add(direction.multiplyScalar(distance));
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).