# Rotating 2D X and Y axis

Tags: three.js

I want to rotate the X and Y axis like in the following picture:

[image]

Scenario is like this:

!! In this scenario the Z axis is the 3D up and down axis and does not server any importance !!

At the start of the scene you are a 3D character looking at Y. You can move left and right along the X axis with the following code:

```
camera.position.x += 1; OR camera.position.x -= 1;
```

You can also turn your camera and look towards another point. This will be point Y1 in picture 2. I rotate the camera object via the following code:

```
camera.rotation.z += 1; OR camera.rotation.z -= 1; //Normally Z is Y.
```

Now when you try to move along the X axis, you will still move along the original X1 axis instead of the new X2 axis.

My question is, how do I make the object move along the new X2 axis instead of the old original X1 axis?

Comment: Three.js makes direction vectoring easy. See the accepted answer here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38052621/moving-the-camera-in-the-direction-its-facing-with-threejs

Comment: Thanks, how do I mode it left/right though? I can't seem to figure that out...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suggest you know about *Object Space* and *World Space*, you can look this book [3D Math Primer for Graphics and Game Developmen](https://tfetimes.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/F.Dunn-I.Parberry-3D-Math-Primer-for-Graphics-and-Game-Development.pdf)

Actually, `camera.position.x += 1` makes the camera translation along World Space X axis, at the beginning, the *World Space* was same as *Object Space*, when you rotated the camera with `camera.rotation.z += 1`, the *Object Space* was changed, you want to translate along *Object Space* axis, you should use `camera.translateX(0.1)`. the camera would translate in *Object Space*.